# Rails plugin to clean up (reformat) html output?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, plugins, rubygems

Is there any plugin (gem) that after rendering page can clean and reformat it? By cleaning I mean removing unnecessary new lines and whitespaces.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies if this is too orthogonal an answer:  You should consider just making sure gzip compression is enabled.  This makes it easier to view your src pages for debugging, requires less fiddling, and is a bigger win then simply removing unnecessary whitespace.  If you have Apache as the front end, you could use mod_deflate (e.g., [How do I gzip webpage output with Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/250566/how-do-i-gzip-webpage-output-with-rails)) and other servers have similar gzip support.  Most modern browsers support gzip, so you'll get the biggest bang for your buck.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are looking for http://www.railslodge.com/plugins/455-rails-tidy Jason's point about ensuring gzip is enables is super important as well.