# rails: how to send the xml page result in a zip file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, web-services, zip

I have a problem with my webservice! As I render xml files just like a web page, the content gets loaded very slowly... Is it possible to render the xml in a zip format?

Thanks for any hints concerning this topic!

Markus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your web hosting should support `gzip`. Compression for delivering the webpage is not handled by Rails, talk to your web hosting for this feature. [Read this question for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/250566/how-do-i-gzip-webpage-output-with-rails)