# How to compress JSON with gzip in Rails for Android?

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails-3, json, gzip, httpclient

I am running Rails 3.2.7 with Ruby 1.9.3p194 to output JSON data from an SQLite database.

```
render :json => result.to_json
```

An Android application consumes the JSON file which gets loaded via `HTTP-GET`:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(urlPath);
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpGet);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
String result = EntityUtils.toString(entity, HTTP.UTF_8);
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
```

### Platform support:

I read in the API that [Rails offers gzip support](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Gzip.html) as follows:

```
ActiveSupport::Gzip.compress(result)
```

I also guess from [HTTP/1.1, RFC2626, section 14.3](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.3) that I can configure the header of a HTTP request:

```
httpPost.setHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");
```

I also found the information quite interesting that are contained in [section 3.5 "Content Codings"](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.5):

> - All content-coding values are **case-insensitive**.
> - HTTP/1.1 uses content-coding values in the **Accept-Encoding** (section 14.3) and **Content-Encoding** (section 14.11) header fields.
> - The Internet Assigned Numbers Authority (IANA) acts as a registry for content-coding value tokens. Initially, the registry contains the
>     following tokens:
>
>   - **gzip** An encoding format produced by the file compression program "gzip" (GNU zip) as described in RFC 1952 [25].

This post further explains [how to handle GZIP encoded content with Android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1576513/356895).

### Server testing:

Thus, I have no clue, how I can find out, if the data has been compressed by the server.
To test, whether Rails outputs gzip, I tried to use *curl* as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/251012/356895):

```
$ curl --head -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip" http://localhost:3000/posts.json
```

The output, however, does not reveal to me, whether gzip is supported or not:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
X-Ua-Compatible: IE=Edge
Etag: "f6f6732c747466f75052f88b1eff393b"
Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
X-Request-Id: 74ee0562c05adea679deb701f1b8fd88
X-Runtime: 0.004205
Content-Length: 0
Server: WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/1.9.3/2012-04-20)
Date: Thu, 16 Aug 2012 23:33:25 GMT
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

I also tried the `--compressed` parameter of [*curl*](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) ...

```
$ curl --compressed --head -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip" http://localhost:3000/posts.json
```

which outputs the same header information as the previous command. When I run ...

```
$ curl --compressed -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip" http://localhost:3000/posts.json
```

the JSON data is printed to the console as readable text. I cannot see if compression has happened. Maybe, because *curl* already decompresses the response?!

### Online testing

I also tried the online test [HTTP Compression Test](http://www.whatsmyip.org/http-compression-test/) mentioned [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/543). It confirmed that the JSON content "is not gzipped". The second website [GIDZipTest](http://www.gidnetwork.com/tools/gzip-test.php) linked [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/4613) acknowledged the negative test result.

### Questions:

1. How can I output gzip compressed JSON from Rails?
2. How do I configure the HTTP client to request gzip compressed data?
3. Does the same configuration still work, when I run the Rails server on Heroku (PostgreSQL), ...?

---

### Lessons learned

As I learned all I have to configure for the REST server is `use Rack::Deflater`. To be clear: I do not use `ActiveSupport::Gzip.compress()` in my code. In case someone is interested, this is what the header looks like when GZIP compression is enabled.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
X-Ua-Compatible: IE=Edge
Etag: "8170a04be41673bf25824256740a9460"
Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
X-Request-Id: 700b9536f6a20164d31b8528bde423af
X-Runtime: 0.369337
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Server: WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/1.9.3/2012-04-20)
Date: Tue, 21 Aug 2012 12:10:48 GMT
Content-Length: 20
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

Now that I know the magic keyword it is easy to [search and find articles on `use Rack::Deflater`](http://bit.ly/PtAmzg).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

maybe you should use Rack::Deflater?
insert in config.ru:

```
require ::File.expand_path('../config/environment',  __FILE__)
use Rack::Deflater
run MyAppName::Application
```

and configure your http request headers:

> I can configure the header of a HTTP request:
>
> httpPost.setHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");

P.S. the same configuration works on Heroku

Comment: Do I need to create a Rack application in order to run it on Heroku? I do not have experience with Rack applications. My project is a simple Rails app.

Comment: No,you don't need create something "special". Deflater is middleware component and you have Rack compatible web framework (Rails 3), just use it. That's all :)

Comment: Can you please add explanations to your answer, why I do **not** need to use `ActiveSupport::Gzip.compress()` but only have to configure `use Rack::Deflater`?

Comment: JJD, I don't know what to say:) Probably you can use ActiveSupport::Gzip.compress() but you also should implement another logic related to HTTP compression (what already had implemented in Deflater https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/deflater.rb). Deflater is common solution for whole application.You can use it for all server resources, I think.