# Compress JSON string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I have this JSON string return by a post request and I'm under ruby on rails:

```
{"a":[{"id":2816,"tr":990,"lub":"mattia1.lipreri","p":"0.20","b":"0"},{"id":2817,"tr":992,"lub":"mattia1.lipreri","p":"0.20","b":"0"},{"id":2818,"tr":993,"lub":"mattia1.lipreri","p":"0.20","b":"0"},{"id":2819,"tr":994,"lub":"mattia1.lipreri","p":"0.20","b":"0"},{"id":2820,"tr":995,"lub":"mattia1.lipreri","p":"0.20","b":"0"}]}
```

I'd like to know if there is a way to compress it, maybe with hpack or cjson, any hint?
Thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11997110/how-to-compress-json-with-gzip-in-rails-for-android

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the bson gem: http://rubygems.org/gems/bson . It's used on mongodb driver internally.

Answer (score 1):

some links  that can help you..!!

http://artsy.github.com/blog/2012/02/24/10x-rack-and-rails-output-compression-with-rack-deflater/

[How to compress JSON with gzip in Rails for Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11997110/how-to-compress-json-with-gzip-in-rails-for-android)